# How to select features from an MsiPackage contained in a Bundle element?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix-extension, wix3.8

I have a exe I created using WiX Burn v3.8. Let's call it Bundle.exe. In this bundle, I have an MSI with 3 features, two are nested under the one. I want to call Bundle.exe from the command line and pass the selected features into my MSI. I should note that I have an existing UI that let's the user select which features to install, so I don't want to use the WiX Bootstrapper app.

```
//Fragment of my MSI.wxs

    <Feature Id="One">
      //ComponentRefs
      <Feature Id='A' >        
        //ComponentRefs
      </Feature>
      <Feature Id="B" >
        //ComponentRefs
      </Feature>
    </Feature>

//Fragment of my Bundle.wxs

    <Bundle>
      <Chain>
        //List of MsiPackages
      </Chain>
    </Bundle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default bootstrapper this is how we pass the arguments from command line:

```
<Wix>
  <Bundle> 
    <Variable Name="CommandLineArgument" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage>
        <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArgument" Value="[CommandLineArgument]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Make a note of the BAL:Overridable. That's how I was able to make sure that we can pass the property value from command line. Don't forget to add the namespace declaration to the Wix element xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension", and link to the WixBalExtension.dll.

In your case, the MSI property that you should be assigning the feature value[s] should be "ADDLOCAL".

```
<MsiProperty Name="ADDLOCAL" Value="[CommandLineArgument]"/>
```

To execute the bundle from commandline do the following:

***bundle.exe CommandLineArgument=One,A,B***

Comment: I'm seeing a warning with this solution:
> warning CNDL1149: The 'ADDLOCAL' MsiProperty is controlled by the bootstrapper and cannot be authored. (Illegal properties are: 'ACTION', 'ADDLOCAL', 'ADDSOURCE', 'ADDDEFAULT', 'ADVERTISE', 'ALLUSERS', 'REBOOT', 'REINSTALL', 'REINSTALLMODE', or 'REMOVE'.) Remove the MsiProperty element. This restriction will be enforced as an error in WiX v4.0.